# Create documentation similar to ebay's api documentation

Tags: c#, asp.net, documentation-generation, ebay-api

We are developing a very complex eCommerce portal using asp.net c# and the client asked us to make the documentation very similar (look & feel) with the [ebay api documentation](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/GetSingleItem.html).

Do you have any idea what kind of tool they are using and if not do you know anything that can be configured to produce a similar result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to their website, [SolutionSet](http://www.solutionset.com/portfolio/casestudies/ebay) custom designed the eBay developer site specifically for eBay.

There is a link at the bottom of the documentation page you linked to stating that the docs were generated using a custom version of the [apireferencedocs](http://developer.ebay.com/community/codebase/apireferencedocs/default.aspx) tool. You could try downloading that and seeing if you get anywhere, if only just for the general look and feel that you could apply to your own generated documentation from another tool.

Comment: you are right .  apireferencedocs tool is a modified version of JavaDoc . Thank you very much for your answer !